# How to install "Advanced Analytics Extensions" using Amazon AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to run this simple Python script inside SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) connected to my instance at AWS Relational Database Service (RDS):

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'import sys
print(sys.version)';
GO
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 39020, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1
Feature 'Advanced Analytics Extensions' is not installed. Please consult Books Online for more information on this feature.
```

So, I'd like to install 'Advanced Analytics Extensions' for SQL Server. I wasn't able to `ssh` into SQL Server EC2 instance and the only solution I had access so far was to install SQL Server and 'additional features' (including R and Python) on the client side.

Is there a way to enable Python script in AWS RDS or even install 'Advanced Analytics Extensions' using command `EXECUTE` inside SSMS ? Or maybe run `SSH`, get into EC2, install Python and run via SSMS interface ?

I also tried to `SSH` using:

```
ssh -N -L 22:my-rds-address.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 ec2-user@???server.com -i ~/ServerKey.pem
```

but it didn't work either, because I can't get the DNS of RDS EC2.

I could try to change this via aws cli:

```
aws rds modify-db-parameter-group --db-parameter-group-name groupname --parameters "ParameterName='external scripts enabled',ParameterValue=1,ApplyMethod=immediate"
```

but the biggest issue seems to be this: external scripts enabled / Modifiable=false:

[image: ModifiableFalse]

Comment: Rubens - am in the same boat, did you resolve this?

Comment: No, I didn't because at the time of the question, AWS didn't provide sysadmin roles to DBA user, @Pand005

Answer (score 0):

We could see that ' Advanced Analytics Extensions' feature is not installed on your SQL Server. As to your question on how to install  Advanced Analytics Extensions using 'EXECUTE' command, we could not find any related material.

- When you install  'Advanced Analytics Extensions' (R Services) on SQL
  server,  make sure to select at least one language during initial
  setup: either R or Python, or both.
- After setup, to execute sp_execute_external_script, you must first
  enable external scripts by using the statement,

> ```
>  EXEC sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;  
>  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; 
>  GO
> ```

This property is OFF by default.

- Restart SQL Server to make this change effective.
- To see the affected changes run the following command:

> ```
> EXEC sp_configure  'external scripts enabled';
> Go
> ```

- After running the above command,you could see that both config_value and run_value changes to 1.
- After the SQL Server Launchpad starts you should be able to run
  simple R scripts.

  Hope this helps.

Comment: Almost. I got this error: Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 105 |  User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 2 | You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.

Comment: When I go to server properties/permission, I get `rdsa error`. I also tried `GRANT ALL ON database1 TO rubens;` without success

Comment: This error is generated because you do not have the appropriate permission of **sysadmin or serveradmin**. To execute **sp_configure** or to run the RECONFIGURE statement, you must be granted the server-level permission by your DBA.